# Calling web service from salesforce to salesforce by using session id

Tags: apex-webservice

I am trying to achieve to call webservice from force.com sites to salesforce providing sessionid such that i will be able to do that logic using that user see below web service

```
global class Webupdateopportunity {

    webService static Id QTC(String opid) {

    system.debug('opp id here'+opid);
    opportunity p = [select id,Create_Order__c From opportunity Where id=:opid];

    p.Create_Order__c=true;
    update p;
    return p.id;
    }

}
```

can any one please suggest me the sample class to call this service from apex class providing session id

Comment: can any one please reply #apexclass

Answer (score 0):

Sites users don't have ability to update standard objects. I believe the reason for this is to prevent solutions that avoid purchasing Sales Cloud or Service Cloud licenses.

There are some workarounds proposed by others:

1. [Update a custom object that behind-the-scenes, mirrors to a standard object](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000B5wHIAS) or, [a more complete answer from SFSE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27374/workarounds-for-sites-page-to-update-standard-object) relying on `without sharing`.
2. [Call a REST service using some predefined user/pw](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009FJzIAM)

I imagine that #2 could be adapted by using invoking a SOAP service in a similar way

Comment: i appreciate your response thankyou so much do we a sample class for the #2 that helps me.