# Issue with Quote with public visual force page

Tags: apex, quote, public

We have the below requirement :

We have a payment request object as a related list in Opp and a custom button on Opp "Send Payment Request". Once clicked on this button (this is part of managed app - Chargent), a payment request is created under opp with status = Sent and the customer (account/person account) gets an email with a link to make a payment(this is a public visual force page using site - part of managed app). Once the payment is completed by customer, the app updates the status of the payment request as Paid.

We would like to make an automation as soon as its changed to paid, we would like to send an email to the customer with a copy of the quote PDF. So we are generating the quote and quote pdf programmatically using apex class and sending to the customer.

This works fine when we test internally by changing the status of the payment request to Paid. But when we test this using payment screen, it throws an internal salesforce error.

Here is the code snippet. The error is coming on the line 122 where we do this action: `b = pg.getContentAsPDF();`

> Error : Internal Salesforce Error.

**Code**

```
public class generatePDFQuoteOnlinePayment{


    public class payment {
        @InvocableVariable(label='RecordID')
        public String recordID;
        @InvocableVariable(label='Status')
        public String status;
    }

    @InvocableMethod(label='Generate PDF')
    public static void generatePDF(List<payment> payments) 
    {
        payment pr = payments[0];

        String QuoteID;

        Opportunity opp = [select id,Pricebook2Id,owner.email,name,accountid,account.personcontactid,account.billingstreet,account.PersonEmail,account.billingcity,account.billingstate,account.billingpostalcode from opportunity where id =: pr.recordID];

        List<Opportunitylineitem> lstOpplineItems = [SELECT Id,ListPrice,Name,OpportunityId,PricebookEntryId,Product2Id,ProductCode,Product_Family__c,Product_Name__c,Quantity,TotalPrice,UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId =: opp.id];

        List<OpportunityContactRole> lstOppContactRoles = [SELECT ContactId,contact.email,Contact.mailingstreet,Contact.mailingcity,Contact.mailingstate,Contact.mailingpostalcode,Id,IsPrimary,OpportunityId,Role FROM OpportunityContactRole where OpportunityId =: opp.id and IsPrimary = True];


        system.debug('Status' + pr.status);

        //Create the quote once the payment request is sent to the customer
        if(pr.status == 'Created' || pr.status == 'Manually Sent' || pr.status == 'Auto Sent')
        {
            String MailingStreet = '';
            String MailingCity = '';
            String MailingState = '';
            String MailingPostalCode = '';


            //List<contact> listContacts = [select id,email,name,MailingCity,MailingCountry,MailingPostalCode,MailingState,MailingStreet,accountid from contact where id =: lstOppContactRoles[0].contactid];

            //Take the address from the contact linked with the opp
            if(lstOppContactRoles.size() == 0)
            {
                MailingStreet = opp.account.billingstreet;
                MailingCity = opp.account.billingcity;
                MailingState = opp.account.billingstate;
                MailingPostalCode = opp.account.billingpostalcode;

            }
            else
            {
                MailingStreet = lstOppContactRoles[0].Contact.mailingstreet;
                MailingCity = lstOppContactRoles[0].Contact.mailingcity;
                MailingState = lstOppContactRoles[0].Contact.mailingstate;
                MailingPostalCode = lstOppContactRoles[0].Contact.mailingpostalcode;
            }

            //Create the quote here
            Quote q = new Quote();
            q.OpportunityId = opp.id;
            q.name = 'Quote : Online Payment - ' + Opp.Name;
            q.Notes_about_your_order__c = 'N/A';


            q.Status = 'Draft';
            q.BillingStreet =MailingStreet;
            q.BillingCity =MailingCity;
            q.BillingState =MailingState;
            q.BillingPostalCode =MailingPostalCode;

            q.ShippingStreet =MailingStreet;
            q.ShippingCity =MailingCity;
            q.ShippingState =MailingState;
            q.ShippingPostalCode =MailingPostalCode;
            q.Pricebook2Id = opp.Pricebook2Id;

            insert q;

            //Create quote line items based on opp line items

            List<QuoteLineItem> listQuoteLineItem = new List<QuoteLineItem>();
            for(Opportunitylineitem OppLineItem : lstOpplineItems)
            {
                QuoteLineItem qlt = new QuoteLineItem();


                qlt.PricebookEntryId  = OppLineItem.PricebookEntryId ;
                qlt.Product2Id   = OppLineItem.Product2Id  ;
                qlt.Quantity   = OppLineItem.Quantity ;
                qlt.UnitPrice   = OppLineItem.UnitPrice  ;
                qlt.QuoteId   = q.id ;

                listQuoteLineItem.add(qlt);
            }

            insert listQuoteLineItem;
        }
        else //The payment request is now paid, hence a quote PDF will be created and sent to the customer
        {
            List<Quote> quotes = [select id,contactid,email from quote where opportunityid =: opp.id limit 1];
            List<Quote> quotestoUpdate = new List<Quote>();
            if(quotes.size()>0)
            {
                QuoteID = quotes[0].id;
                String quotetemplateID = '0EH24000000yKo7';
                String quoteUrl = '/quote/quoteTemplateDataViewer.apexp?id=';
                quoteUrl +=QuoteID;            
                quoteUrl +='&headerHeight=190&footerHeight=188&summlid=';            
                quoteUrl +=quotetemplateID ;            
                quoteUrl +='#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&zoom=90';

                //Create pdf content
                PageReference pg = new PageReference(quoteUrl) ;

                //Document object of quote which hold the quote pdf
                QuoteDocument quotedoc = new QuoteDocument(); 

                Blob b;
                if (Test.IsRunningTest())
                {
                    b = Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST');
                }
                else
                {
                    b = pg.getContentAsPDF() ;
                }


                //content assign to document
                quotedoc.Document = b;

                //assign quote id where pdf should attach
                quotedoc.QuoteId = QuoteID ;

                //insert the quotdoc
                insert quotedoc; 


                EmailTemplate templateId = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'Customer VAT Receipt'];

                /// Send the email to the customer
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                // Create the email attachment with the quote PDF created above
                email.setTemplateID(templateId.Id);

                if(lstOppContactRoles.size() == 0)
                    email.setTargetObjectId(opp.account.personcontactid);
                else
                    email.setTargetObjectId(lstOppContactRoles[0].contactid);

                email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
                efa.setBody(b);

                String[] toAddresses;
                if(lstOppContactRoles.size() == 0)
                    toAddresses = new String[] {opp.account.PersonEmail};
                else
                    toAddresses = new String[] {lstOppContactRoles[0].contact.email};

                //String[] toAddresses = new String[] {opp.account.PersonEmail};
                String[] ccAddresses = new String[] {opp.owner.email};

                email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
                email.setCcAddresses( ccAddresses );
                //email.setPlainTextBody( 'This is a simple email body' );
                email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

                Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r =
                    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email}); 


                //Once the email is sent to the customer with Quote and PDF attached, the quote status will be changed to accepted.
                quotes[0].status = 'Accepted';
                quotestoUpdate.add(quotes[0]);

                update quotestoUpdate;

                //Finally the Opp stage will be changed to Invoiced.
                opp.StageName = 'Invoiced';

                update opp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone faced this or a similar issue? Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: This might be a long shot: Did u consider that the Public Site User runs with different permissions/profile than any internal User? Check the FLA and whatnot for that profile on your public site.

Comment: Yes have given access to all required objects for the public profile, but interesting we cannot see Quote object under CRUD in public profile , but it appears in internal profiles. When I read in internet, it says SF does not allow quote access to external users, not sure if this is true.

Comment: Check of permission if it is supported by the license and profile.

Comment: What is user license license of Site user? is that `Guest`? If so then you can only have Read and Create permission on Quote

Comment: There are workarounds: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27374/workarounds-for-sites-page-to-update-standard-object

Comment: @SantanuBoral Yes its using Guest License. Still when we go to the public profile we cannot see the quote object in the list of standard objects under CRUD. So I supposed SF by default gives access to quote objects.

Comment: @ChristianSzandorKnapp I am not sure if this related to giving access to standard object for site users (we still need to figure out why public profile does not have access quote object in CRUD). The error is really coming on the function : getContentAsPDF(), when I read articles I see that SF has changed this a call out and I dont know how this works with guest users and calling that in invocable methods. But then again why this works from internal users.

Comment: I'd suggest editing out the references for the Quote in the PDF Call and try again. Then at least u know if it's quote related or not.