# Force.com IDE "Unable to refresh resources: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id (Failed)"

Tags: force.com-ide

I'm trying to create a new project from a sandbox environment, but when it tries to download the default metadata (just code components), I get this error:

Unable to refresh resources:

INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id (Failed)

I know that Eclipse and the Force.com IDE are working, because I was was able to create projects from other Salesforce orgs. The user account I'm using in the sandbox in question has a full System Administrator profile, and I can't see any reason why I would be able to get a list of the metadata components in the org, but then not be able to download them. I went into the project properties and unchecked "Use Tooling API deploy path when possible" under Force.com > Deployment Options, but that didn't help resolve the problem.

I'm familiar with getting the "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id" when doing data loads, etc., but I don't remember encountering it in a metadata context before. Any ideas as to why I might be getting this error, and what I can do to fix it?

I'm using Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and the Force.com IDE 38.0.0.201701101558

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My troubleshooting seems to have narrowed it down to a dependency on a Wave Analytics Permission Set License for the user trying to download the metadata (this org uses the Financial Services Cloud managed package, which has a companion Financial Services Cloud - Wave managed package, mostly likely the dependency culprit). The error thrown by the Metadata/Tooling API is completely useless in the troubleshooting, let's hope they get something better soon...

Comment: You are right, it looks like a license issue. Got similar question on stackexhange. 
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5546/how-to-fix-insufficient-access-rights-on-cross-reference-id