# Inserting record on Junction object with formula fields

Tags: trigger, formula-field, before-trigger, junction-object

I have Junction object called Agreement Scope which has two Master Detail relationships with Account and Agreement.

We are assigning Account and Agreement in the lightning components Apex Controller and doing an insert DML.

> I am getting INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY exception.

Unfortunately I am not able view the stack trace.

I tried giving all the FLS to running user profile and even view all and modify all to the records, still it is throwing the error.

What can be the reason for this?

On the junction object there are some formula fields from Account and Agreement, especially from Account, Account Name.

I can view values for these in before insert calls.

Comment: Could this be a sharing issue? Is the running user able to see both records? What sharing behaviour have you declared on the apex class being used as the controller?

Comment: Yupp, when I copied the record ids of both agreement and Account, and viewed them with user. both were visible.

Comment: Please read through the answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5546/how-to-fix-insufficient-access-rights-on-cross-reference-id/17152#17152) for more on this particular error.  There's a number of different items that could be causing the error.  Also, the `Account` and `Agreement` records both have to exist first, so you may need to run your insert in an `after` trigger context