# Can change the ownership(to internal user) of custom object record by Site Guest User

Tags: apex, permissions, profile

We have lightning community, in which we have drag and drop component.

After onclick of button, we are updating custom object 'contact survey' record owner id. In `@AuraEnabled` method we are updating the owner id of the 'contact survey' with parent custom object 'account' 's ownerId.

Error:

> System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Comment: First take a look [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5546/how-to-fix-insufficient-access-rights-on-cross-reference-id) to see if it could be any of those issues causing this error

Comment: @BrianMiller, i have checked but this does not help me. This is due to owner Id update. if we comment the line of owner updating then we dont see this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have add new permission "View All User" to profile of guest user. 
[image]

Comment: Or you can place the ownership-changing method into a "without sharing" class, rather than giving unauthenticated users super-broad permissions.