# How to avoid "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id" error when inserting a master detail child of Contact by a Community User?

Tags: sharing, contact, customer-community, accountcontactrelation

I have a custom object, `Ticket__c`, that has a master detail field to `Contact`. I have a Digital Experience accessed by "Customer Community" licensed users. One of the pages provides access to the related list of `Ticket__c` records for the Contact related to the given Community User.

The org's OWD sharing of "Account and Contract" for External Users is "Private", and "Contact" is "Controlled by Parent".

The Community User's profile ensures that the user has permission to create `Ticket__c` records with all necessary fields and has Read and Edit access to `Contact`.

The Related List page in the digital experience (community) appropriately provides a "New" button and clicking it shows the creation form with the master detail `Contact` lookup field pre-filled with the user's related Contact. However, an attempt to save the record results in "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id" (rather annoyingly this error message gives no hint as to which field or ID this relates to, but I have narrowed it down to the Contact master detail).

Now, I'm quite certain it is all related to the sharing on `Account` being Private and the fact that `Account` is the parent of `Contact` from the sharing perspective in the community context.

I've found some other references to this issue, including an unhelpful [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328226&type=1&mode=1), along with [this other Stack Exchange Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5546/how-to-fix-insufficient-access-rights-on-cross-reference-id) where a relatively recent answer talks about providing Modify All permissions to work around the problem. This isn't a suitable solution for me so I continued looking at what I could do here.

Salesforce supports the idea of `Sharing Sets` for community use, accessible in Setup under Feature Settings > Digital Experiences > Settings, that seemed like a plausible solution so created a `Sharing Set` against `Account` determining access using `User:Contact.Account = Account.Id`, granting `Read Only` access (I don't believe the community user needs to be able to edit, only read).

Unfortunately this didn't help. On revisiting this configuration I noticed a second tab, "Share Group Settings" and found that there was a button to Activate the Share Group. So I clicked it.

I waited a few minutes (the scratch org I'm on has next to no data on it at this point so thought this shouldn't take long) and tried creating a `Ticket__c` again but still got the same error.

Anyone got any ideas as to how I can solve this problem without having to inappropriately share Accounts?

Comment: have you tried granting more access in that `sharing set`? Does the account have any rollup fields or anything similar related to contacts?

Comment: AFAIK you will have to reference the Account in the sharing set. Exposes less than "View All".

Comment: Hey @KeithC can you explain more? That I basically what I thought I was doing with the Sharing Set...

Comment: Hi @KrisGoncalves what do you mean by "more access"? Do you mean write instead of read only? I am not aware of any roll ups but I will check.

Comment: Hi @PhilW, Yes I'm saying use the sharing set and I have that working - using `User:Contact.Account = Account:Id` - in a community for a similar setup. Presume your sharing set is tied to the right profile? Beyond that I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: @KeithC I wonder if it is the license type? I am targeting "Customer Community" and this has least capability with Sharing from what I understand...

Comment: Hi @PhilW, The license types I am using are "Customer Community Login" and "Customer Community Plus Login" (pricier). For the first, sharing sets have to be used, and it is possible to set "View All Records". For the second, sharing rules can be used but it is not possible to set "View All Records". Haven't used "Customer Community".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has per @KrisGoncalves's comment, I updated the Sharing Set to allow Read/Write for the selected Account and it started to work.

**UPDATE**:

I realized why read/write sharing is required for Account. Since Account is the parent (in sharing terms) for Contact and Contact is the master details parent for `Ticket__c`, I actually have to have write sharing on Account to have write sharing on Contact and write sharing on `Ticket__c`. In effect, the error was a bit misleading and was essentially saying I couldn't create my `Ticket__c` object because I didn't have write permission for any `Ticket__c` - the `Contact` isn't owned by me, as a community user, so isn't write shared with me (and thus in turn I have no way to manage master detail children regardless of profile permissions) unless and until its parent is write shared with me in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

My wild ass guess is that Contact has a required standard field that's can't be written to.

And to find the exact field - put the logic into a unit test.

Start with a method that has one runas user - the customer community user.
Duplicate the problem.

Then fix that with a method that has two runas users - one with a customer community profile - and another for the saving user having a profile that has "modify all data".

Once you know what the field is - and you have a "fix" - you can go down the path of making the field writeable. Might not be easy.

Comment: I did not need to change any permissions on Contact or Account, but rather make the Account write sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of errors when trying to enable Customer portal users to edit their account and to create new contacts.

This is what i did to solve the errors, hope this help someone:

[Portal user cannot edit own account and cannot create new contacts (portal users cannot own partner accounts)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/368108/portal-user-cannot-edit-own-account-and-cannot-create-new-contacts-portal-users)