# Unable to Import a Report into Marketing Cloud from Service Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, marketing-cloud-connect, import

Our org was recently integrated with our service cloud application and I can currently sync over objects.  When I attempt to import a report into marketing cloud via EmailStudio --> Interactions --> Import, I do not see the Salesforce Objects and Reports location, even though it appears in the file locations within setup.

We are also unable to send via the connector in journey builder.  Our API user is properly integrated (as am I) and the connection has been established.  Please advise - below is the error in journey builder (even though we have the stated permission).

,INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY;insufficient access rights on cross-reference id;;Process Activate failed. Unable to activate the Journey, the Sales Cloud user may not have correct permissions. Activating a Journey requires Manage Salesforce CRM Content permissions.

Comment: Not sure why it is happening, since there could be many reasons, including MC Connector is not fully configured correctly but there are also a lot of articles mentioning the same error, e.g. [this one](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000R0huQAC) or [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/5546/99298).

Answer (score 2):

At this point, you would want to reach out to Support. There could be a lot of different issues that could be causing this.

As a best practice, please ensure that the Salesforce System User is assigned the System Administrator profile.

You will also want to ensure that the Marketing Cloud API User is integrated, as well as your own Marketing Cloud user. Refer to the Knowledge Article below to complete this:

Connect your Marketing Cloud user with your Salesforce user
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000354555&type=1&mode=1

Comment: I resolved the issue by creating a new file location pointing to Salesforce Objects and Reports location.  For some reason, my marketing cloud org did not like the standard Salesforce Objects and Reports file location that was generated with the connector.