# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY and Criteria-Based Sharing Rules

Tags: owd, criteria-based-sharing

See also this [well-trod question/answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5546/how-to-fix-insufficient-access-rights-on-cross-reference-id)

**Given**

- OWD of Private on `Lead`
- afterInsert trigger on Lead inserts (via Apex) a child `Task` pointing at the parent `Lead` via `WhoId`
- Criteria-based sharing rules grant R/W access by `User X` to Leads of the nature inserted by `User X`

**When**

- Lead is inserted from API by running `User X`

**Then (per debug log)**

- Lead's afterInsert trigger fails with `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` at the moment of `Task` DML insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general principle behind most `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` errors is that the running user doesn't have access to a referenced (i.e. lookup) record due to Record sharing rules.

For example, the Apex transaction in question is effectively:

```
API: insert new Lead(fldA = ..., fldB = ..., ...);

Apex: 
...
void onAfterTriggerHandler(Lead[] recs) {
   Task[] tasks = new List<Task>();
   for (Lead l : recs) {
      tasks.add(new Task(..., WhoId = l.Id, ...);
   }
   insert tasks;  // INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY occurs here
}
```

If running User X can insert the Lead, why can't it insert a Task pointing at a Lead it just created, given that the Criteria-Based sharing rules give `User X` R/W to Leads inserted with field values provided by `User X` in the original API call?

And the answer is ...

- If one of the fields provided in the initial Lead insert is an `OwnerId` other than `User X` or
- Before insert trigger/flow logic changes the inserted Lead's `OwnerId` to a value other than `User X`

Then because criteria-based sharing rules aren't applied until the `after Insert` is completed, the `Task.WhoId` points at the Lead owned by some other `User Y`. Since the Lead's `after Insert` is still in flight,  the operative sharing rule is OWD Private. Thus running `User X` can't yet see the Lead it just inserted as the inserted Lead referenced by `WhoId` is owned by `User Y`.

Your workaround depends on your application; for example, delegate the creation of the Tasks to an async transaction like future or queueable. By the time the async transaction starts, the Criteria-based sharing rules will have been applied by SFDC and the Lead will be visible to `User X`, regardless of its ownership.