# How to solve " We can't display this information, ask your admin for help"

Tags: case, related-list

I have a request where the user is unable to send an email from SF to the client. After additional research, I discovered that there are no contact details for the case. Instead, it displays the error "We can't display this information, please contact your administrator" in the related list.

****Note:****

This is happening only in one case.

what could be the reason and How to handle this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id:[] is a common issue when you try to update or create data with insufficient access on a record.

Kindly check the user profile and check whether the user has access to insert/update that record. Even if the user has access, kindly check whether the user has access to update fields like record types, lookup field, master-detail field, etc.

Troubleshooting steps:

Make sure whether the user has access to record ids of the lookup fields and/or master-detail fields in the record.

Check the user Profile(CRUD Permissions).

Profiles need to have access to the record types.

Record's OwnerId automatically gets a shared record when the record is inserted. If the apex code tries to create the same(Share record for the owner) explicitly. This error occurs.

Check whether the apex code is trying to create share records to the record in which the current user doesn't have access to it.

Note:

Even though trigger runs in System Mode, Sharing Settings will be checked. Only CRUD and FLS will not be checked against the user.

For further reference, you can check the below too,

['insufficient access rights on cross-reference id'](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328226&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

[How to fix insufficient access rights on cross-reference id?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5546/how-to-fix-insufficient-access-rights-on-cross-reference-id)